# Or filtering with PostGraphile not working

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

I am trying to search multiple fields in one query with the use of the OR and filter.

```
query SearchQuery($searchTerm: String) {
  allArtists(
    filter: {surname: {includesInsensitive: $searchTerm}, or: {firstname: {includesInsensitive:  $searchTerm}}}
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        firstname
        surname
      }
    }
  }
```

Both `surname` and `firstname` will return results if done separately, however when combining with a `OR` it will return no results.

Is it possible to search multiple fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` takes all options and combines with AND. The `or` option takes a **list** of filters and combines them with OR. Since you only want the OR condition you need to supply your options inside the OR list:

```
query SearchQuery($searchTerm: String) {
  allArtists(
    filter: {or: [
      {surname: {includesInsensitive: $searchTerm}},
      {firstname: {includesInsensitive:  $searchTerm}}
    ]}

  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        firstname
        surname
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Genius!! Off topic, but is it possible to search for a `full name` I have a first name = "jamie" and surname = "hutber" and if I search for `jamie hutber` it will only return one result?

Comment: You could add a computed column for full_name and filter against that. You may be better off looking into full text search with tsvector/tsquery/etc though, it will often better match your users’ expectations